# How to make spring boot microservices consistent while using Eureka for service discovery?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, consul, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-zookeeper

The main criteria for choosing service discovery type is CAP theorem.
https://www.ibm.com/in-en/cloud/learn/cap-theorem
C- Consistency
A- Availability
P- Partition Tolerance

It says a distributed system can deliver only two of three desired characteristics: consistency, availability, and partition tolerance. **One of these characteristics is always traded off.**

**Eureka gives AP,
Consul CA,
Zookeeper CP**

In my project the developers are using Eureka, how can we make your services consistent?

Comment: Eureka was built for massive scale. Mitigations are used to overcome eventual consistency such as retry. eureka client uses local caches that may be up to 90 seconds out of date.

Comment: mitigations as in ? is a library? sorry, I am not cleaar.

Comment: retry with spring-retry or resilience4j